# Unable to communicate to my ECS Service from a running EC2 instance over port 443?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-security-group

I have an ECS Service running a couple of tasks in a private subnet and an EC2 instance in the same VPC but in a public subnet. I want to be able to communicate with my ECS service via my EC2 instance over port 443. My ECS is configured to use a certain domain.

When I run nmap from my EC2 instance, I get the following :

```
nmap -Pn <domain-name> -p443

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2023-05-24 20:35 UTC
Nmap scan report for <domain-name>
Host is up.
Other addresses for <domain-name>
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.03 seconds
```

However when I do the same using the IP address of the running task, I'm getting the following:

```
nmap -Pn <Private-IP> -p443

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2023-05-24 20:27 UTC
Host is up (0.00099s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

When I run `ping <domain-name>` I am getting the following:

```
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5106ms
```

However I am able to ping the private IP of the running task from my EC2 instance.

```
ping <private-IP>

4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
```

I have configured the inbound security group of my ECS Service to allow traffic from the public subnet like this.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "inbound_https" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.inbound.id
  type = "ingress"
  from_port = 443
  to_port = 443
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["<public-IP-cidr>"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "inbound_icmp" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.inbound.id
  type = "ingress"
  from_port = 0
  to_port = 0
  protocol = "icmp"
  cidr_blocks = ["<public-IP-cidr>"]
}
```

And I can see from the UI that they were applied successfully.

I am confused because the ingress is allowed, yet I am still not able to open port 443 into my ECS service via my EC2 instance. I checked the NACL and they allow all traffic from all ports. What am I missing?

The Task definition is as follows:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "<TASK-DEF-ARN>",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "<NAME>",
            "image": "<IMAGE>",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 2048,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "awslogs-group",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-stream-prefix"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "<FAMILY>",
    "taskRoleArn": "<TASK-ROLE-ARN>",
    "executionRoleArn": "<EXECUTION-ROLE-ARN>",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 63,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "2048",
    "registeredAt": "2023-05-24T21:25:20.965Z",
    "registeredBy": "<REGISTERED-BY>",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "Environment",
            "value": "dev"
        },
        {
            "key": "Region",
            "value": "us-east-1"
        },
        {
            "key": "Service",
            "value": "My Awesome Service"
        },
        {
            "key": "Stage",
            "value": "<STAGE>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I even opened up port 80

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "lcp_inbound_http" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.lcp_inbound.id
  type = "ingress"
  from_port = 80
  to_port = 80
  protocol = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["<public-IP-cidr>"]
}
```

And the `nmap` is still filtered.

```
nmap -Pn -p80 <DNS>

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.04 seconds
```

Comment: Do you have the domain-name configured somewhere?
the domain name should point to the internal IP using DNS records, then, after it is propagated you should be able to actually access it

Comment: @NicolasdeLima It is configured in Route53 and is pointing to the ALB for the ECS Service which is further pointing to the correct internal IP of the tasks. I can reach the DNS just fine via the browser as well. Just something is weird about the SG.

Comment: I am also able to ping the IPs directly.

Comment: You gave me a good idea, maybe i'll try manipulating the inbound SG of the load balancer itself.

Comment: Did you ensure that the security group associated with your EC2 instance allows outbound traffic on port 443 to the ECS service's security group?

Comment: Yes, the outbound traffic was open to all, so ["0.0.0.0/0"].

Comment: IC, well I have no Idea. Wish you good luck, here's a couple of things I would check:

Ensure that the security group associated with the ALB allows inbound traffic on port 443 from the public subnet where your EC2 instance is located. --
Confirm that the target group associated with the ALB has the correct settings and is correctly registered with the ECS service tasks --
Verify that the security group associated with the ECS tasks allows inbound traffic on port 443 from the ALB's security group

And also check with nslookup if the DNS is actually correct

LMK if you solve this man

Comment: Thank you @NicolasdeLima ALB allows inbound traffic on port 443 from the public subnet where your EC2 instance is located -> This scenario is looking a lot likely.

Comment: Are you trying to bypass the load balancer for the communication between the EC2 server and the ECS service? If so, does the ECS service even have a container that has an SSL certificate installed and listening on port 443? Are you sure you aren't terminating SSL at the load balancer? I would really need to see the ECS task definition to understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: @MarkB Yes. Port 443 is open. I am able to access the app via https using the browser. another one of my EC2 instances is able to `nmap` using port 443 against the app. I will post the task definition above.

Comment: The app is in a private subnet. So you are always going to be going through the load balancer when you test it in the web browser. If your EC2 instance is not going through the load balancer when it tries to connect to the app, then that test you did in the web browser isn't really telling you anything.

Comment: Looking at the task definition, I can see that the container itself is NOT listening on port 443 and does NOT have an SSL certificate installed. It is only listening on port `80`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the `<public-IP-Address>` in the inbound rule and that worked.